# Why does the AddField method in the Wordpress Redux framework not work?

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I am currently using version 4.1.18, which is the latest version of the Redux Library. I proceed according to the [documentation](https://devs.redux.io/core-fields/color.html) on the site of the Redux library. Fails in AddField method in coding. Why does it give?

[Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRG8I.png)

Answer (score 1):

Lead dev of Redux here. It will in the release coming tomorrow. There was a bug in a release which we have resolved.  :)